# Reference the value of a key in a typescript object

Tags: typescript, typing

```
    type obj = { a: 1, b: "one", c: true }
    function updateObj(key: keyof obj, value: obj[typeof key] ) {

    }
```

Currently the parameter; value in the updateObj function is a union of all the values of the type obj. However, i want it to reference only the value of the key that was passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the function generic. Use a generic parameter to represent the key that you get, and use that to access the key's value type:

```
type obj = { a: 1, b: "one", c: true }

declare function updateObj<K extends keyof obj>(key: K, value: obj[K]);

updateObj("a", 1)      // No error
updateObj("a", 5)      // Error here
updateObj("a", false); // Error here
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKygXigbygQwFxQIwA0UcuARDAHYSlEDGuwATgK7QC%20AUBwCYS0A2mRtABmzCrWABLSlGZhumYBADyiADwBpKBAAeyitwDOUANYQQMEbEQA%20ABTmQuTUQBumfq1zwEAbU0AXQBKAG4ueUVlNQR7UkwafGCOSKVVRDiEogBWYKh8goB6QqgAUUZGGEYUhTSYzMSRTyMIMKhisoqqjiA)